# How do I divide blocks in my page with flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm facing this problem where I want to have a header, sidebar and content with flexbox. I can't get to a solution to divide these 3 childs. I've been trying to use flex-grow and flex-direction:row but I'm having a problem.

[Image of the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PO3Rt.png)

[How I want it to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfBtM.png)

```html
<style>
.parent {

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
  height: 100vh;
  border: 20px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: cornflowerblue;
}

.side {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: rgb(219, 133, 133);
}

.content {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: rgb(115, 202, 180);
}

.text {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 190px;
  color: #fff;
}
  </style>

   <div class="parent">
    <div class="header">
      <h2 class="text">Header</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="side">
      <h2 class="text">Side</h2>
    </div>
    
    <div class="content">
      <h2 class="text">Content</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Search the web for 'flexbox holy grail layout'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create two containers, one for all your elements and one for your header and content.

```
<div class="parent"> <!-- Container 1 -->

  <div class="side">
    <h2 class="text">Side</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="container"> <!-- Container 2 -->
    <div class="header">
      <h2 class="text">Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <h2 class="text">Content</h2>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Then, you can treat each container as a separate flex-box. the `parent`  will have a `flex-direction: row;` and the `container` will have `flex-direction: column;`.

You also want to set values in percentages, not absolute values as you have right now (200px, 20rem..).

```
.parent {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 20px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.header {
  height: 30%;
  background: cornflowerblue;
}

.side {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgb(219, 133, 133);
}

.content {
  height: 70%;
  background: rgb(115, 202, 180);
}

.text {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 190px;
  color: #fff;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xzqontdc/2/)

Images to illustrate the separation:
[image]
[image]

Comment: One question, why is the flow direction of the parent set as row? Isn't flex-direction row horizontal? The side is vertical so what causes the sidebar to be vertical while the flex-direction is set as horizontal? Hope you understand what I mean :D

Comment: This is counter-intuitive and something that took me a lot of time to get used to, `flex-direction: row` separates the elements into columns (1 row), and `flex-direction: column` separates them into rows (1 column). 

To remember it think about it as a line of text. Text is laid out in a line, in 1 row. 
When you have a long piece of text, the text is laid into one long row of text. This is the `row` direction. When you have a lot of text that is being stacked into multiple rows, you get 1 long column. This is the `column` direction`.

Comment: `row` - The flex container's main-axis is defined to be the same as the text direction. The main-start and main-end points are the same as the content direction.

`column` - The flex container's main-axis is the same as the block-axis. The main-start and main-end points are the same as the before and after points of the writing-mode.


If you want to get deeper into it, you can read about it here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Is it answering your question? :)

Comment: It is! Thank you so much! Took me a long time to get used to aswell haha :D

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap your header & content section inside another div. Something like this below example.  However, The best way to achieve this layout is using a CSS grid. Here is the [complete CSS grid guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #000;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0;
  
}

.side {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 30vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #fff;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.main-body {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 70vw;
}

.header,
.content {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   background: #fff;
}

.header {
  height: 25vh;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.content {
  align-items:center;
  height: 70vh;

}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="side">
      <h2 class="text">Side</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="main-body">
      <div class="header">
        <h2 class="text">Header</h2>
      </div>
    
      <div class="content">
        <h2 class="text">Content</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you deeply understand how flexbox work. You should read more about it. I advice you to read a book called CSS-in Depth. You can download it online from a website called Z-lib. Try to understand the code that I posted for you.

```
<style>
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .parent {
      height: 100vh;
      border: 20px solid black;
      display: flex;
      background: pink;
    }
    
    .main {
      display: flex;
      backgound-color: green;
      flex-direction: column;
      flex: 2
    }
    .header {
    
      background: cornflowerblue;
    }
    
    .side {
      flex: 1;
      background: rgb(219, 133, 133);
    }
    
    .content {
      background: rgb(115, 202, 180);
      flex: 1
    }
    
    .text {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      height: 190px;
      color: #fff;
    }
      </style>
    
       <div class="parent">
         <div class="side">
          <h2 class="text">Side</h2>
        </div>
         <div class="main">
        <div class="header">
          <h2 class="text">Header</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
          <h2 class="text">Content</h2>
        </div>
         </div>
      </div>
```